# Getting values from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hi i have used dictionary as like below.

```
Dictionary<int, List<double>> conditionbase = new Dictionary<int, List<double>>();
```

in this dictionary i have stored maximum and minimum values based on columnindex as key.

Now i need to get particular columnindex based these max and minimum values?

Comment: **"get particular columnindex based these max and minimum values"**. Show example input data and output data. Do you mean "show all column indices, where I can store value X"?

Comment: Indeed, this question is really not clear at the moment. Additionally, if every list is just going to contain two values (a minimum and maximum) I'd suggest creating a class or struct to represent those two values rather than using a `List<double>`.

Comment: Are there any requirements for search speed? How do you get source `double`s to search (there can be pitfalls within the floating point numbers comparison)? Also, can you change `List<double>` to `Tuple<double, double>` (as far as I understand, there are only two values in the list)?

Comment: I read it as "for a give `List<double>`, show me all keys which match that value"?

Comment: Are the max and min values unique? That is, can multiple columns have the same min and/or max?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is data i have stored in Dictionary
key = 2 , values =  6, 99 stored in list
key = 3 , values = -3 , 99 .
So now my key is 2, i need to access the values stored in list with reference of key in list??

Answer (score 2):

First assuming that the min and/or max values are not unique to a given column index then you want to find the columns that have a particular min and max.

So, ignoring the trickly business of double equality, try something like:

```
var min = 1.0;
var max = 100.0
var columns = conditionbase.Where(x => x.Value.Max() == max && x.Value.Min() == min).Select(y => y.Key).ToArray();
```

or, if your max and min values are at indexes:

```
var columns = conditionbase.Where(x => x.Value[1] == max && x.Value[0] == min).Select(y => y.Key).ToArray();
```

**Note:** Equality comparison of doubles can be *difficult*.

If your list has only a max and a min then consider using a type like:

```
public class Limits
{
   double Minimum {get; set;}
   double Maximum {get; set; }
}
```

Then ... your dictionary becomes:

```
var conditionbase = new Dictionary<int, Limits>();
```

Much better. Lots of options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is data i have stored in Dictionary
key = 2 , values =  6, 99 stored in list
key = 3 , values = -3 , 99 .
So now my key is 2, i need to access the values stored in list with reference of key in list??

Comment: conditionbase[columnIndex][listIndex]